# PHP Remove chars in one list from an other

Tags: php, list, special-characters

I have a list of special chars separated by `|`, lets say `$chars = "@ | ; | $ |";`

And I have an string, let's say `$stringToCut = 'I have @ list ; to Cut';`

I want to remove from `$stringToCut` all chars in `$chars`.

How would I do that ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would convert your list of characters to remove to an array and use `str_replace`:

```
$chars_array = explode($chars);
// you might need to trim the values as I see spaces in your example

$result = str_replace($chars_array, '', $stringToCut);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_replace()` to remove

```
<?php
$chars = "@ | ; | $ |";

$stringToCut = 'I have @ list ; to Cut';
$pattern = array('/@/', '/|/', '/$/', '/;/');
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $stringToCut);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, instead of using regex, just explode the list of chars:

```
$chars = explode('|',str_replace(' ','','@ | ; | $ |'));//strip spaces, make array
echo str_replace($chars,'',$string);
```

`str_replace` accepts an array as first and/or second argument, too [see the docs](http://be1.php.net/str_replace). 
This enables you to replace each char by a distinct counterpart, or (as I did here) replace them all with nothing (aka remove them).

Comment: @vladimire: I'm exploding it, too, I just remove all spaces from that list prior to exploding it. If your string really is `@ | ; | $`, you're replacing substrings like ` ; `<- space-semi-colon-space. That's the only difference. Just so you know